# if a variable or object of type var is null then how to assign a value to it

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

what i am trying to do is ,if row is null then how to programitaclly assign a new row to it

```
var row = (from obj in _objdb.tbl123 where obj.cus_id == hidCusRowId.Value select obj).ToList();

                    if (row == null)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        TextBox objtxt = this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("txt0" ) as TextBox;
                        TextBox objtxtsize = this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("txts0") as TextBox;

                        dt.Columns.Add(objtxt.Text);
                        dr[0] = objtxtsize.Text;
                        List<string> lt = new List<string>();
                        lt.Add(objtxtsize.Text);
                        row.Add(lt.ToList());
                    }

                    GridView1.DataSource = row;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

an error is occured on row.add(lt.ToList())....

Comment: `row` is never `null` because `ToList` never returns null, maybe you mean `row.Count == 0`

Comment: yes it should be 'if (row.count==0)' but this does't  solve my problem

Comment: Well, `row.add(lt.ToList())` can't throw this exception because neither `row` nor `lt` can be null there. You're also doing some weird things i don't understand. For example, you are creating a DataTable which you don't use, you are creating a list but you only assign `objtxtsize.Text` which you then add to the (empty) datasource-list. Why don't you use the datatable as datasource?